# CKEDITOR 4 looks weird - first time user

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

[image: The toolbar is at the right side]

[image]

Hey guys.

This is what happened when I integrated CKEDITOR to my project. This is a normal textarea, where I've added the [Framed](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_framed) Editing.

I have done nothing but to add the code. Haven't touched any files.

Anyone has same problem, or knows what to do? I have no idea what's up here.

Comment: > I have done nothing but to add the code.
What code?

Comment: I've found the problem. The new generated HTML needed to have some width and float left properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated div che_chrome, needs to have a float left and a width. At least that worked for me.